# h2 Padding and Div Positioning

Tags: html, css

Could someone take a look at the following link of a work in progress test page for my new website - http://goo.gl/YwGiB

I'm new to CSS, and I have come across some issues that I can't figure out without some expert help.  Could someone answer me three questions and possibly an explanation of how to amend it?

1) Why does my middle column by default split itself into sections, whereas my right hand column is pretty much the same but does not have the divisions?  What could I do to cause that to default in the right hand column?

2) I am looking to have a box in the right hand column running parallel to the first box titled 'news' in the centre column, and then a second running parallel underneath this (with the box titled 'blog' but it will have an irregular length.  What would be the best way to do this?  Would this be a case for using the standard positioning commands to shift them into place or is there a better way?

3) I have stripped the padding and margins from my h1-h3 tags (specifically the h2 tag) yet there still appears to be space above the lettering.  It is more pronounced when using the font MerceariaAntique which is going to be the final font, but unfortunately I am unable to amend my html file to show this right now.  I am attempting to resolve it by adjusting the line-height but I am not getting anything consistent.  Is there anything else I can do other than make line-height and margin adjustments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your markup, you have divided your sections using the `<div>` element, which is completely acceptable, however you have used the same ID to identify each of them. This is what classes are for. IDs should be unique and only used once on a page, classes can be used to apply the same styles to multiple elements.

So this:

```
<div id="newsitem">
```

should be this:

```
<div class="newsitem">
```

Answers to your actual questions now!

1. By default, paragraph and headings have paddings and margins set. The reason your sections have spaces is down the margin on the paragraph tag. Removing this removes the space, but also brings the text together with the next heading. You can over come this by giving the `<p>` tags 0 margin and giving them padding, or giving padding to the section container instead.
2. If you want the boxes in the right hand column to line up with the ones in the middle column, you'll have to change how your layout works so that you have rows rather than columns I think. That would make it easier to line them up.

   From your description, you should then have the following layout:

   middle column | right column
   middle column | right column
   middle column

   To maintain the background colour of the centre column, you could apply the background-color property to the class .centre or to be more specific .column.centre (this type of CSS selector might not work in IE6 though).
3. The issue with the H2 is down to line-height, each font may have a different line-height so you will have to play with the value until you get it right. If you find you're getting the top position right, but text underneath is getting closer or overlapping, give the H2 a padding-bottom value.

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't realise what you were talking about with the the id/class thing, but then checked my source and forgot that they were once three separate sections!  Totally slipped my mind.  So it looks like it *is* using margins and padding to achieve what I wanted.  I did also think about creating rows rather than columns ,but didn't know how to approach it seeing as the middle column contained similar data, and the lower box in the right column may have differing lengths.

Comment: Yeah, the right column would cause problems if the second one is a variable height. Unless the first box in each column MUST be the same height, what's wrong with how it's laid out now?

Comment: Actually nothing really - they don't have to line up exactly, but I thought it would be good to get to a starting point, and then amend it to what I want later on.  All of that content section will need to be shifted into the header part anyway as I don't like the amount of space there.  The margin problem for the right column is one that I would like to sort though.  I didn't want everything running together, but I'm not sure it will as there will only be one box there in future.  Either way, I think I could use margin and padding to sort that.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using h2 and h3, but I can't find an h1 that you mentioned. I'd remove "line-height" option from your css to prevent wrong/incorrect spacing.

To run div's parallel you need to have the same padding and margin on both divs (the left and right side). To do so just create a class "floatingColumn" that would float to the left and append it to both divs with all the margins and paddings.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I realsied that I did have a h1 tag until I removed my strapline so that is now redundant.  I may hide the h1 under my logo to still get the use out of it.